# Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: Redirect Uri Mismatch

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

JSON File

```
{"web":{"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "client_secret":"c-kaafSexciO7It3QcKxx3BO",
    "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "client_email":"xxx678964-tjkl572knihtgocll9tnadvsdngmnld6@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    **"redirect_uris":["http://www.alfrosia.com"]**,


"client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/798911678964-tjkl572knihtgocll9tnadvsdngmnld6@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id":"xxx1678964-tjkl572knihtgocll9tnadvsdngmnld6.apps.googleusercontent.com",    
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "javascript_origins":["[http://www.alfrosia.com][1]"]}}
```

I am specifying proper redirect url in the json file above, but during authentication it is giving  wrong url message on browser.  While I have given, [this](http://www.alfrosia.com) as Redirect Uri in json file.

In the error message it says that

> redirect_uri=**http://localhost:57826/authorize/**

is uri_mismatch while I have not specified it in json

But Google OAuth2 authorization Failed ,this error message occurs during authentication process

```
- Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.
```

Request Details

```
scope=https:[//www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly][3]
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost:57826/authorize/ 
access_type=offline
pageId=none
client_id=xxxxx964-tjkl572knihtgocll9tnadvsdngmnld6.apps.googleuserconten
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect_uri must exactly match what you have set in the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).    My guess is that your code / client library / IDE is automatically setting the redirect URI based upon the url you are browsing from.

Visual studio for example has a habit of randomly changing the port.

**Option 1:**

Fix your redirect uri in the Google developer console to

> http://localhost:57826/authorize/

**option 2:**

assuming you are using visual studio fix the project settings so it stops adding a random port.

**option 3:**

assuming you are using java or visual studio IDE that may be adding this random port.  Create a `Client ID for native application` instead of a `Client ID for web application` and use that for testing on local host.  Do not release `Client ID for native application` to your live webserver.

Comment: if we put redirect as locahost. Will it work even for website which are published. I mean for published website we need to give an actual redirect right? or this localhost will work?

Comment: In that case you can also just use a native oauth2 code which dosent require refresh uri. But local host should work as well

Comment: Please help me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483697/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch/30484099?noredirect=1#comment69760768_30484099

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is not working in Google developer console.

Try 127.0.0.1 as redirect URI and don't use symbols in the URI.